# why import is not working here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am building numpy and was wondering why they have used the relative imports inside [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L191-204) . Why have they used relative imports instead of direct imports like import fft (say).

I thought direct imports would work so cloned it and changed source [line 197](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L197) to

```
import fft
```

, but it did not work .It threw error as

> ImportError: No module named fft

why is it not able to find fft module even though it is in the [same folder as numpy __init__.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/fft)  .

so I simulated a similar environment to see why it did not work . I created module(mod1) and another (mod2) inside it . and from mod1 __init__.py I imported mod2 and finally added the folder containing module mod1 to python path .
and then wrote a python script as sample.py which contained

```
import mod1
```

and everything worked fine without need for relative import.

But why is it not working here inside numpy ?

Note : I am having numpy inside virtual-env . Is that causing trouble ?

Update on debugging :

```
import numpy.fft
```

worked . and I checked "__name__" and it was numpy . But why "numpy." is needed as it is already in numpy module ??? And more importantly since __name__ was set to numpy it should have been able to figure out the fft module which is within it.Confused why it is not working... My example that I used to simulate is same scenario where I just used the import mod2 despite mod2 was inside mod1 and I did not have to do import mod1.mod2

Comment: `touch __init__.py`?

Comment: fft module has __init__.py (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/fft/__init__.py)

Comment: or may be `from __future__ import absolute_import` before importing.

Comment: no it did not work ..

Comment: how about `from . import fft`? I believe absolute_import from `__future__` changing some nature.

Comment: that is the default ,, which I wanted to change to "import fft" and wondering why it is not working

Comment: @YOU I did not expect that you were pointing at the "from __future__ import absolute_import" the line at the top as the reason for the weir behavior . I thought you were asking me to add ..it .. so got confused.. sorry...so if your comment was similar to answer by Kevin , then you are right ..

Comment: no problem, I was lazy to fully explain as answer. he deserved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

You *cannot* use implicit relative imports when this future statement is active.  You *must* either use a fully absolute import (`import numpy.fft`) or an explicit relative import (`from . import fft`).  See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for further discussion of this.